# undefined method `subtour' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby on rails and learning the fundementals.
I started putting together an app for listing tours and in the app I have tours and underneath this subtours (based on date). I tried to copy the methodology in a way of blog posts and comments in tutorials.

I have subtours related to tours, and they display fine on the tours page, however when I press new subtour, i get the error undefined method `subtour' for nil:NilClass

It is saying the code:

```
<%= form_for([@tour,@tour.subtour, url: url]) do |f| %>
```

In the form file is wrong, but I can't figure out why.

Code is up at https://github.com/daverobertsfilm/coach - appreciate any help

Comment: Can you add controller code too?

Comment: Normally you call it like `form_for(@tour, @tour.subdour, url: url)` without the intermediate array (`[...]`).

Comment: what is the file that has `<%= form_for([@tour,@tour.subtour, url: url]) do |f| %>`?

Comment: Hi, the code is in \app\views\authors\subtours\ _form.html.erb,

Comment: @tadman I tried without the array and it made no difference :/

Comment: The `nil` error is because `@tour` is not defined, which means you must investigate why that's not being set in your controller. Tip: Where it's being assigned, put `Rails.logger.debug("Assigning @tour to %s" % @tour.inspect)` and watch your `log/development.log` to be sure that line of code is being fired. Maybe it's not.

Comment: thanks for the heads up , I have been tweaking with the code noticing the tour wasn't defined, so I rewrote the form and controller to be a lot simpler and so the subtours list in the tour and the when i click new, the form works. however, when saving, it says it cannot find a tour with 'id=' a - i then re-added my error code <% if subtour.errors.any? %> and it says undefined local variable or method `subtour' for #<#<Class:0xc419cd0>:0xbdc85e0> -- i'm not sure where this subtour is defined in the controller? (I have updated my github)

Comment: I rebuilt my app from scratch after more frustration, I think there were some things in the first tutorial I followed that probably affected this, but I think the major thing was the post_id wasn't indexed and didn't have a foreign key, hence it not find an id for tour I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error because `@tour` object is `nil`, you need to set tour in controller action.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, could you expand on this? I'm not quite sure which controller I am setting tour in and how?

Comment: Where did you write the above form_for tag, which file is it?

Comment: Hi, the code is in \app\views\authors\subtours\ _form.html.erb,